# Wamp + Symfony + Perfomance + same PC

Tags: php, ajax, performance, symfony, wamp

[image]

Hi,

Please help me with slow Symfony over WAMP.

Me and my friend from work have same PC but I have 2s waiting for ajax response and he has 0.6s. Whats more I have other PC and there is also ok, around 0.7s.

I tried a lot of things. Now I have newest WAMP, PHP, MYSQL. 
I tried disable eset. 
Wamp is running on SSD.
PC has 3 month. (i7 3.6GHz and 16GB RAM)
Same symfony project.

What Can I do to improvement? I think that 2s for simple ajax is too long time.

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled?

Comment: how complex is the code that is called upon that ajax request? is caching enabled?

Comment: I forgot told you, that is Symfony 3.4.4.

I tried with xdebug enabled and disabled - same time on ajax.

But now I tried again and did:
;zend_extension="..."
And it is working now is 0.9 s ! :) 

Complex of code is easy, very simple.

Comment: But 0.9s for very simple ajax is still to long, right? BTW. Whole symfony is slow

Comment: Fire `composer install -o` you will earn few milliseconds ;)

Comment: Some kind of Anti-virus software with real-time checks active? If so try to exlcude the project directory and especially the cache directory or disable it completely to check if it is a problem.

Comment: EsetNOD32 I tried this and this helped me from 4s to 2s in past

Answer (score 2):

Switch from WAMP to Laragon: laragon.org
Just browse the site and you'll see why. It's the fastest local server, it has a bunch of features that you won't find by default in WAMP or XAMPP...

It's portable too, and it's also easy to migrate projects set up with WAMP to Laragon: https://laragon.org/download/migrate-from-wamp.html

Comment: Thanks for the downvote... It was just a suggestion. You've got my downvote too.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved problem, blocked Mhz on my i7, there was limi 900Mhz, strange